# custom bindinghandler in knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I have div in my html as below..

```
<div data-helper="my helper text1">help</div>
```

Also I have an array in my javascript

```
self.helpers = [
       { name: ' abc ', helper: ' my helper text1 ' },
       { name: ' def ', helper: ' my helper text2 ' },
       { name: ' xyz ', helper: ' my helper text3 ' }
           ];
```

Using knockoutjs, I would like to bind  helper to data-helper text.

Basically I need something which would convert the code below to the necessary html code ..

```
<div databind="helper:helpers.helper">help</div>
```

I tried to create custom bindinghandler but could not..

Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Thanks

Update: I accepted an answer without looking at the code and have to reopen the question.
I need the lines to look as below..

```
<div data-helper="my helper text1">help</div>
```

So, div data-bind:text will probably not work

I tried as below but it did not succeed..

```
<!-- ko foreach: helpers -->
            <div data-bind="attr: {data-helper:helper}">help
            </div>
            <!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Show us what you have for a handler so far, without it (and possibly even more code, enough to form a [mcve]) it's pretty hard to imagine what you're aiming for.

Comment: Are you trying to render html for each item in the array?

Comment: @Neps yes, render html with data-helper atrribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to implement this functionality: [custom component](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-registration.html) and [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html). You can start with the short example below:

```js
ko.components.register('my-component', {
        viewModel: {
            createViewModel: function(params, componentInfo) {
              return {
                helpers: params.helpers
              };
            }
        },
        template: { element: 'my-component-template' }
    });

ko.bindingHandlers.helper = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
          var values = valueAccessor(),
              $templateHtml = $('#my-component-template').text(),
              $element = $(element).append($templateHtml);
            var childContext = bindingContext.createChildContext(values);
            ko.applyBindings(childContext, $element.children()[0]);
            return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
        }
    };

ko.applyBindings([
       { name: ' abc ', helper: 'my helper text1' },
       { name: ' def ', helper: 'my helper text2' },
       { name: ' xyz ', helper: 'my helper text3' }
           ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/html" id="my-component-template">
    <div>
        <!-- ko foreach: helpers -->
            <div data-bind="text: helper, attr: { 'data-helper': helper }">
            </div>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
</script>

<div>Component:</div>
<my-component params="helpers: $data"></my-component>

<div>Custom binding:</div>
<div data-bind="helper: { helpers: $data }"></div>
```

The custom component consists of the registration code ("ko.components.register('my-component'...") and template ("...").

#### Update 1.

I've added custom binding example. You can check [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) for more details.

#### Update 2

You should wrap attr name with quotes:

```
<div data-bind="text: helper, attr: { 'data-helper': helper }">
</div>
```

Comment: OP asked specifically (though for unknown reasons and in a vague manner) for a custom *binding handler*, not a component.

Comment: Thanks, @Jeroen, I've updated the answer. IMHO component is a better way.

Comment: @TSV updated the question with more info, I do not have a problem with either a component or custom binding handler but the code in each line has to look as '<div data-helper="my helper text1">help</div>'